# C/C++ getnameinfo ai_family not supported

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I use a library that does some nework stuff and when a client connects, this library provides a "struct sockaddr *" which holds the client socket. I simply wanted to extract the IP and port and I do it currently this way:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>

const std::string Client::prepareIPandPort(struct sockaddr *hostaddr) {
    assert(hostaddr != nullptr);

    std::string ipport;
    char clienthost[NI_MAXHOST];
    char clientport[NI_MAXSERV];
    int result = getnameinfo(hostaddr, sizeof(*hostaddr),
                             clienthost, sizeof(clienthost),
                             clientport, sizeof(clientport),
                             NI_NUMERICHOST | NI_NUMERICSERV);

    if (result != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error: " << gai_strerror(result) << std::endl;
        ipport = "unknown";
    } else {
        switch (hostaddr->sa_family) {
            case AF_INET:
                ipport = std::string {clienthost} + ":"
                         + std::string {clientport};
                break;
            case AF_INET6:
                ipport = "[" + std::string {clienthost} + "]:"
                         + std::string {clientport};
                break;
            default:
                ipport = "unknown";
        }
    }

    return ipport;
}
```

When using IPv4 on my Mac, it works. If I use this application on my Gentoo Linux server with full IPv6 support, I only get:

Error: ai_family not supported

The connecting client has AAAA and IP6 records in place.

I added some couts and printed hostaddr->sa_family, which returns 10, which is AF_INET6.

Why does this not work? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `sizeof(*hostaddr)` because `hostaddr` is a generic `sockaddr*` pointer.  Different address families use different `sockaddr_...` types, which are not all the same size as `sockaddr` itself.  `getnameinfo()` needs to know the *true* size of the `sockaddr_...` struct that `hostaddr` is actually pointing at, based on its address family.

Per the Linux [`getnameinfo()` documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html):

> EAI_FAMILY
>   The address family was not recognized, **or the address length was invalid for the specified family**

`sockaddr_in` (IPv4) is the same size as `sockaddr`, which is why `getnameinfo()` is "working" for IPv4.  But `sockaddr_in6` (IPv6) is larger than `sockaddr`, which is why `getnameinfo()` fails.

The best solution is to have the caller pass in the correct size:

```
const std::string Client::prepareIPandPort(struct sockaddr *hostaddr, int hostaddrlen) {
    ...
    int result = getnameinfo(hostaddr, hostaddrlen, ...);
    ...
}
```

```
sockaddr_in ipv4host;
...
client.prepareIPandPort((sockaddr*)&ipv4host, sizeof(ipv4host));
```

```
sockaddr_in6 ipv6host;
...
client.prepareIPandPort((sockaddr*)&ipv6host, sizeof(ipv6host));
```

Otherwise, you have to calculate it:

```
const std::string Client::prepareIPandPort(struct sockaddr *hostaddr) {
    ...
    int hostaddrlen;
    switch (hostaddr->sa_family) {
        case AF_INET:
            hostaddrlen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
            break;
        case AF_INET6:
            hostaddrlen = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);
            break;
        default:
            std::cerr << "Error: " << gai_strerror(EAI_FAMILY) << std::endl;
            return "unknown";
    }
    int result = getnameinfo(hostaddr, hostaddrlen, ...);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there some way to find out, if the sockaddr carries IPv4 or IPv6?